# Android - How do I display input method picker automaticly whenever activity is shown?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-input-method, background-foreground

TLDR version: I want to switch between input methods with the least amount of taps possible. `InputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker()` does nothing when called in MainActivty `onResume()`, but works when added to a button. I guess the issue is caused by my app not yet being in the foreground when `showInputMethodPicker()` is called.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    SettingChanger.inputMethodPicker(this)
}

fun inputMethodPicker(context: Context) {
    val imeManager: InputMethodManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

    // current default input method (before change)
    val inputMethodNameBeforeChange = Settings.Secure.getString(
        context.contentResolver,
        Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD
    )

    // Brings up the keyboard picker
    imeManager.showInputMethodPicker()

    if (inputMethodNameBeforeChange.contains("swiftkey")) {
        // Turn off bluetooth
        bluetoothAdapter.disable()
    } else {
        // Turn on bluetooth
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            context.startActivity(enableBtIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

Long version:

I use a Hungarian physical keyboard with my Android phone and my preferred virtual keyboard does not register all its characters; however a different one does, so whenever I connect the physical keyboard via Bluetooth, I have to switch to a different virtual keyboard, and back again when I'm done.

The option to change input method is deeply hidden in the settings, so I wrote an app which simply opens the input method picker and - to make my life a little easier - turns Bluetooth on/off based on which method I'm about to use.

I want the input method picker to pop up automaticaly, but when I switch to my app from a different place, my `inputMethodPicker(context: Context)` function - which I call in `onCreate()` - does not show the input method picker, but shows the Bluetooth-On request when it's appropriate. If I lock the phone with my app on the screen and unlock again, the input method picker pops up as expected.

My `inputMethodPicker(context: Context)` function works as expected when attached to a button.

My guess is that the issue is caused by my app not yet being in the foreground when `showInputMethodPicker()` is called.

(I tried creating a main menu widget, witch executed my `inputMethodPicker(context: Context)` just fine, but the function did nothing, probably also because of some foreground/background issue I guess.)

What can I do to show the input method picker and the Bluetooth-On request whenever the activity is shown? (or when tapping my main menu widget button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My whacky hack that seems to work is delaying the function call a little bit:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Handler().postDelayed({ SettingChanger.inputMethodPicker(this) }, 50)
}
```